# AIR for iOS Sound.play() stops background music

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

In the game I'm building there are sound effects and music. Players are able to turn off the in-game music and sound effects. I assume that when a player turns off the in-game music it's probably because they want to listen to their own music. However, when I run a Sound.play() in order to play a sound effect the background music being played from the music app is stopped. Is there a way around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please reread your question and think to yourself while you do, "Have I given enough information, code, facts to get a detailed answer, or have I been to vague."

Comment: @The_asMan: I thought I had given enough information. It's a very simply problem: I'm loading sounds using the `flash.media.Sound` class. And when I use the `play` function the music from the music app stops. It's pretty simple. There's nothing more to it, I think.

Comment: If it was that simple you would have fixed it already. My point is and I can't stress it enough in order to find that one line of code that is giving you problems we need to see that line of code. Just by saying I am playing a sound and all other sounds stop when I do doesn't give enough description. When asking a code related question it is best to post the offending code. And you never know you might learn something about your coding style from the masters on this site.